# phpbb3 codeigniter library session error

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

```
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /includes/session.php on line 1024: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /application/libraries/phpbb_library.php:1)
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /includes/session.php on line 1024: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /application/libraries/phpbb_library.php:1)
[phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file /includes/session.php on line 1024: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /application/libraries/phpbb_library.php:1)
```

How to fix this ?

I red in the phpbb3 library author theme, one of the posts has the same issue, and he fixed it by ‘not cloasing the controller file’, but what did he mean realy ? Sme help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that he removed `?>` in the end of some php file.

But in your case all you need is just to cut off the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) from the `/application/libraries/phpbb_library.php` file

Comment: worked, but it wans't the BOM it was the UTF-8, change it to ANSI and now works, thanks.

Comment: @shearwar: `BOM` is a marker placed in unicode files. After you converted a file to ANSI - it became one-byte, thus without `BOM`. And be careful, you might have lost some characters that don't exist in ANSI (but exist in unicode).